# Pandas dataframe : create new ID variable based on number of modalities of an existing one

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Dataframe df contains an ID variable containing IDs of groups of observations. But the ID values has "holes" (can be 1,3,4,7 without 0,2,5,6).

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ], 'b': [7, 8 , 9, 10, 11, 12],
                   'id': [1, 4, 4, 7, 3, 1]})

   a   b  id
0  1   7   1
1  2   8   4
2  3   9   4
3  4  10   7
4  5  11   3
5  6  12   1
```

My goal is to replace the existing ID variable with a new one starting from 0 to the the max number of IDs I have in the original ID variable, such as.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 ], 'b': [7, 8 , 9, 10, 11, 12],
                    'id': [0, 2, 2, 3, 1, 0]})

   a   b  id
0  1   7   0
1  2   8   2
2  3   9   2
3  4  10   3
4  5  11   1
5  6  12   0
```

Any idea how to do this please?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You're basically looking for a dense ranking, only starting from 0 instead of 1, e.g. `(df["id"].rank(method='dense')-1).astype(int)`.  I'm sure this is a duplicate, though, so I'm looking for one now.

Comment: @DSM I found a suitable target.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`pd.factorize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.factorize.html) supports this:

```
df['id'] = pd.factorize(df['id'], sort=True)[0]

#    a   b  id
# 0  1   7   0
# 1  2   8   2
# 2  3   9   2
# 3  4  10   3
# 4  5  11   1
# 5  6  12   0
```

Comment: There seem to be hundreds of results brought up by searching for pd.factorize.  It seems unlikely that none of them are close enough to use a duplicate.

Comment: @DSM, I looked. Maybe not hard enough, but I couldn't find it. One used `apply`, none use `sort` argument. It was quicker to post an answer.